# What is the difference between db.coll.UpdateMany() and db.coll.BulkWrite() in mongodb 4.2

Tags: mongodb

I use db.coll.UpdateMany() update 1w data, is costs about 3 seconds, the filter is

```
{ id: { $in: { 1, 1..., 12 }}, { $set: { time: now() }}}
```

Comment: Can you edit your question for clarity: what driver & version are you using and what differences are you interested in?

Comment: I want to know which is faster at the same update data size.

Answer (score 0):

Running both updates in a 4.2 `mongo` shell will result in the same command being sent to the server: the shell's [`updateMany()` collection helper](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/6874650b362138df74be53d366bbefc321ea32d4/src/mongo/shell/crud_api.js#L668) constructs an [ordered bulk write](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/bulk-write-operations/#ordered-vs-unordered-operations) operation.

The difference in the shell API is that [`db.collection.bulkWrite()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/) supports an array of [write operations](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/bulk-write-operations/#bulkwrite-methods) (which can be different CRUD operations for one or many documents) while [`db.collection.updateMany()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/) is a single update operation affecting all matching documents.

The bulk write command provides a superset of `updateMany()`'s functionality, which is why the `mongo` shell rewrites a single `updateMany()` operation into a `bulkWrite()`.

Comment: I want to know which is faster at the same update data size.

Comment: @light-x As per my answer: assuming you are testing in the `mongo` shell, `updateMany()` is  implemented as a `bulkWrite()` with that single update operation so there will be no difference in outcome.